# How to use the HostListener decorator correctly to call a superclass function?

Tags: javascript, angular

I´m currently struggling replacing the *host* metadata by *HostListener* and *HostBinding* according to the [official Angular styleguide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#hostlistenerhostbinding-decorators-versus-host-metadata). The starting point is as follows: I have a custom directive inherited from ng bootstrap superclass ngCheckBox. In the old spelling with the host metadata everything worked great. But if I now try to switch to the new best practice, I get the error message:

```
Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
    at CustomCheckBoxDirective.NgbCheckBox.onInputChange
```

I suspect that I am using the decorator HostListener incorrectly.

**How can I use the HostListener correctly to access a superclass function?**

---

*CustomDirective with host metadata:*

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[customButton][type=checkbox]',
  host: {        
    '(change)': 'onInputChange($event)'        
  },
  providers: [CUSTOM_CHECKBOX_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CustomCheckBoxDirective extends NgbCheckBox {
  constructor(private myLabel: CustomButtonLabelDirective) {
    super(myLabel);
  }
}
```

*CustomDirective with HostBinding / HostListener:*

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[customButton][type=checkbox]',
  providers: [CUSTOM_CHECKBOX_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CustomCheckBoxDirective extends NgbCheckBox {      
  @HostListener('change') changeListener($event: any) {
    this.onInputChange($event);
  }      


  constructor(private myLabel: CustomButtonLabelDirective) {
    super(myLabel);
  }
```

*NgbCheckBox super class*:

```
export declare class NgbCheckBox implements ControlValueAccessor {       
    // ...
    onInputChange($event: any): void;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to tell angular to pass in the event object like this, otherwise, nothing is passed which means your argument assumes `undefined` as its value

```
@HostListener('change', ['$event'])
changeListener(event: any) {
    this.onInputChange(event);
}
```